# Azure Functions Scaling

Tags: azure-functions

*Any help in this regards is much appreciated as I'm new to the subject and I'm unable to arrive at a conclusive answer reading the documentation.*

Reference: [Azure Functions host.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Http-Functions)

Scenario: 
Auto-scaling of Azure Functions when values for  **maxOutstandingRequests,**  **maxConcurrentRequests and dynamicThrottlesEnabled.** are set to a finite positive number?

Question: 
1. Would it start throwing Http 429 or scale automatically by adding more instances? 
2. What happens when concurrent requests bring-in more than 1.5GB of data in-memory?

Comment: It depends on the Plan which is selected while the function is created. For Consumption plan it is handled automatically. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

Comment: @Baskar For now, let us limit the scope to consumption plan only.

Answer (score 3):

> 1.Would it start throwing Http 429 or scale automatically by adding more instances?

If **exceed** the max concurrentRequests and dynamicThrottlesEnabled is **true** then it will throwing **429**. And the dynamicThrottlesEnabled value should be **boolen** type.

> **maxConcurrentRequests**: the maximum number of http functions that will be executed in parallel. The default is unbounded (-1). **In these cases, applying a throttle here can help**. The default is unbounded(-1).
>
> **dynamicThrottlesEnabled**: requests will be rejected with a 429 "Too Busy" response until the counter(s) return to normal levels. The default is **false**.

---

> What happens when concurrent requests bring-in more than 1.5GB of data in-memory?

In your scenario, it should also return **429**. when dynamicThrottlesEnabled is enabled, it will also check the **connetions/threads/memory/cup etc**.

> When enabled, this setting will cause the request processing pipeline to periodically check system performance counters like **connections/threads/processes/memory/cpu/etc**. and if any of those counters are over a built in high threshold (80%),**requests will be rejected with a 429**

Comment: maxConcurrentRequests is unbounded only for App Service Plan. For Consumption Plan it defaults to 100.